# What's the advantage of using cotton braid wires over normal wires?

Tags: wire

I recently notice sudden trending use of cotton braid wires over
normal wires in eletronic units. Is there any special advantage to it?

[image]

Google shows me about images but not helping with advantages.

Comment: Advantage: it looks like old fashioned wiring for the more traditionally inclined person. Other than that it's hype, smokescreens, mirrors and subterfuge.

Comment: there is probably an advantage for the manufacturer in higher profits

Comment: They look nicer when newer but look worse when older.

Comment: @DKNguyen have you used it anytime to comment ?

Comment: My mouse and keyboard used to have them. Oh yeah, dust also sticks to them better, and you can't just wipe them down because bits of tissue get stuck onto them, though I suppose you could use a wet cloth but I'd rather not on a cloth cable.

Comment: Cats and dogs like to destroy thin cables by chewing them. Textile surface can hold a substantial amount of Off or other bad tasting repellent. Off at least has been effective in directing the chewing activity to elsewhere than to my cables.

Comment: @user287001 One person's bane is another person's boon I guess. I hate how textile cables hold onto crap that can't easily be cleaned off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real difference is aesthetic. While you *might* see some differences in durability, that would ultimately be down to the manufacturing quality, rather than the materials used.

I suppose the cloth-shrouded cables also have worse insulation, but that barely matters, as all the wires are individually insulated anyway, and these cables are not used for any voltages high enough for the shroud insulation to matter.

Comment: Why worse insulation barely matters?

Comment: @FoxyM Because when you are running 5V through it, it doesn't matter if your insulation goes from 300V to 250V.